# Why sudo cp doesn't work when I run in a custom Mac App but works when I run in the shell of Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, sh, sudo, finder

In Terminal I move to Desktop and I create a folder App1.app with this commands (change <your_user> for your own Mac user):

```
cd /Users/<your_user>/Desktop
mkdir App1.app
```

Then I move into App1.app:

```
cd App1.app
```

I create a new file with next command:

```
touch App1
```

I type this text inside this new file to run as script this script (using `vi App1` command) :

```
#!/bin/sh
export PASSWORD=<CHANGE THIS FOUR YOUR ROOT PASSWORD>
#CHANGE THIS FOUR YOUR PATH TO A FILE OF INSTALLED APP LIKE WHATSAPP
export FILE_PATH=/Applications/WhatsApp.app/Contents/Info.plist

echo "$PASSWORD" | sudo -S cp "$FILE_PATH" "${FILE_PATH}.backup"
echo "$PASSWORD" | sudo -S cp "$FILE_PATH" "/Users/<your_user>/Desktop/Info_plist.backup"
exit
```

Once I write this file (with 'Esc' ':' 'wq' 'Enter') I change the user and group of the app:

```
chown -R root:wheel .
```

At last I try to run this App using double click from the Desktop or from Terminal using this command:

```
open /Users/<your_user>/Desktop/App1.app
```

This action copy the file in Desktop, but the file inside the installed application is not copied.

But if I return to terminal and I run:

```
/Users/<your_user>/Desktop/App1.app/App1
```

the two files are copied, even the installed application one.

Is there any way to get the same behavior of the terminal when I run the script like an standar application?

NOTE:
I tryped to copy a file of the inside of TextEdit app but it won't copy inside the TextEdit.app folder.

NOTE 2:
I tryed to added the same permission to the App1 like the Terminal, even the Total disk access, but may be I was doing something wrong or I forgot some grant.

EDIT: As sugest me in the comments I put the result of the trace information of the fail here:

```
+ export PASSWORD=<my root password>
+ PASSWORD=<my root password>
+ export FILE_PATH=/Applications/WhatsApp.app/Contents/Info.plist
+ FILE_PATH=/Applications/WhatsApp.app/Contents/Info.plist
+ echo <my root password>
+ sudo -S cp /Applications/WhatsApp.app/Contents/Info.plist /Applications/WhatsApp.app/Contents/Info.plist.backup
Password:cp: /Applications/WhatsApp.app/Contents/Info.plist.backup: Operation not permitted
```

And I put also the trace information when I run in the Terminal:

```
+ export PASSWORD=<my root password>
+ PASSWORD=<my root password>
+ export FILE_PATH=/Applications/WhatsApp.app/Contents/Info.plist
+ FILE_PATH=/Applications/WhatsApp.app/Contents/Info.plist
+ echo <my root password>
+ sudo -S cp /Applications/WhatsApp.app/Contents/Info.plist /Applications/WhatsApp.app/Contents/Info.plist.backup
Password:+ echo <my root password>
+ sudo -S cp /Applications/WhatsApp.app/Contents/Info.plist /Users/acayon/Desktop/Info_plist.backup
+ exit
```

Comment: We can't really say what's going on. Could you add `set -ex` and `exec >/tmp/ooops.log 2>&1` to the beginning of the script, run it once, remove those lines again, and show the contents of `/tmp/ooops.log`?

Comment: I tried and the content of file is:
+ export PASSWORD=<my root password>
+ PASSWORD=<my root password>
+ export FILE_PATH=/Applications/WhatsApp.app/Contents/Info.plist
+ FILE_PATH=/Applications/WhatsApp.app/Contents/Info.plist
+ echo <my root password>
+ sudo -S cp /Applications/WhatsApp.app/Contents/Info.plist /Applications/WhatsApp.app/Contents/Info.plist.backup
Password:cp: /Applications/WhatsApp.app/Contents/Info.plist.backup: Operation not permitted

Comment: (Thanks for the update; generally please [edit] your question rather than hide debugging information in comments. You get better control over the formatting, too.)

Comment: I'm guessing the Apple gatekeeper process prevents you from writing random files into the app's directory. Probably simply copy the file somewhere else where you don't even need the `sudo`.

Comment: (You should not need `sudo` for the second command, either; you should already have write access to your own files. Perhaps also replace `/User/<your user>` with simply `"$HOME"`.)

Comment: (And, you should not make `root` the owner of your private script file.)

Comment: As you suggest me I edited the first message to add the trace of the script when fails, and also when works. This example I write in the first message is a simplification of the real escenario. I would like to understand why Mac generates Operation not permited when I run through the finder, but it works when I run in terminal. I don't know what is "Apple gatekeeper", but I think that the sudo command must grant super user permission and allow access to all this files. And

Comment: Also I run sudo in every command because I tryed to run sudo at the only first commad but as it fails I tryed to do every command to tryed it because it seams that every command is runing separately (I will try to remove if I get it works)

Comment: I notice that if I run the command open App1.app in the terminal also fails. May be the open command has any option to grant access to work with all files?

Comment: It says something like "Terminal would like to access your Desktop folder" and then if you click Allow it's allowed after that. If you are not running the command from Terminal you separately need to grant the same access to the other process which needs the privilege.

Comment: (As a further aside, there is no need to `export` this variable if it's only used by the script itself. Putting your password in your script is a really bad idea for other reasons; a much better solution is to grant passwordless `sudo` access to a script which performs these actions.)

Comment: The password in the script is for an example proposal. Really I get the password using Apple Script asking with a dialog and then I use this result in the commands, but it is not writed in the script directly.

Comment: I don't know how, buy I get to run using chmod permission with the next command sudo chmod 4777 App1.app/App1. Doing this I can get the same behavior in the Terminal and in the Finder.

Comment: Whatever you are hoping to accomplish, **`chmod x777` is *wrong* and *dangerous.*** You will want to revert to sane permissions ASAP (for your use case, probably `chmod 4755`) and if you have had world writable system files on a public-facing system, at the very least investigate whether it could have been breached and used as a pivot point for breaking into your organization’s network.

Answer (score 0):

I found by mylef a solution for this problem. It seems that it can be solved with "the setuid bit).

According with man of chmod command:

```
4000    (the setuid bit).  Executable files with this bit set will run with effective uid set to the uid of
                   the file owner.  Directories with this bit set will force all files and sub-directories created in
                   them to be owned by the directory owner and not by the uid of the creating process, if the
                   underlying file system supports this feature: see chmod(2) and the suiddir option to mount(8).
```

I suppose that it allows to run the internal script of the my custom App with root privileges.

Because of it I can remove the sudo command of the script and with a simply cp command the files can be copied.

Comment: NOTE: It only works if the files I want to copy own to my own user and the parents folders of the file are also own to my own user.

Comment: If any know how to allow root own files It will be perfect.